# How to configure plain text email signature for Office365?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web, email-signature

I have changed my [mail settings to plain text](https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/options/messageformat) for the Outlook webapp. I also added a [signature](https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/options/mailsignatures) with the delimiter `--`:

```
-- 
Philipp Kretzschmar
Software Developer
```

Yet whenever I send mails to my private account via the office365 webapp, the signature is not showing as a signature but as part of the email message body, making the mail way too verbose and I am unsure where I go wrong.

(Sending plain text with mail correct marked signature was working fine via the mutt client, yet it doesn't work via the web frontend.)

How to properly set up a valid plain text email signature in Office365?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think OP has any issues switching between HTML and plain text formatting; the issue is that when OWA is set to plain text composition mode signatures aren't inserted, either automatically (when so configured) or by manually using the Insert Signature button from the tool ribbon.  You can work around this by temporarily switching the message format to HTML, inserting the signature, and switching back to plain text, but that's pretty awkward for every day use.

I haven't yet found a better solution--- likely just one more piece of evidence that Microsoft developers don't actually use their own products.

Answer (score 0):

The below image shows how to change from HTML to TXT in Outlook on the web (Office 365).

[image: Outlook on the web (Office 365]